# Django: if in list template tag

Tags: django

Is it possible to write a template tag that will check the contents of a list?

Currently I have the below checking from 5 to 13, but this is very verbose and I will need to do this nine times.

```
{% if wizard.steps.current == '5' %}                    
    <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathtwo/" %}{{display_image}}"/>                                                                     
    <section>   
    <span class="tooltip"></span>   
    <div id="slider"></div>  
    <span class="volume"></span>  
    </section>      
{% endif %}
{% if wizard.steps.current == '6' %}            
    <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathtwo/" %}{{display_image}}"/>                                                                     
    <section>   
    <span class="tooltip"></span>   
    <div id="slider"></div>  
    <span class="volume"></span>  
    </section>      
{% endif %}
    ...
    ...
```

I have tried

```
{% if wizard.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'] %}              
    <img src="{% static "survey/images/paththree/" %}{{display_image}}" />                                                                      
    <section>   
    <span class="tooltip"></span>   
    <div id="slider"></div>  
    <span class="volume"></span>  
    </section>      
{% endif %}
```

But get an error

> Exception Value:   Could not parse the remainder:
>   '['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13']' from
>   '['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13']'

Any ideas?

Comment: Define the list in your view and do `{$ if var in list %}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to create an "In" filter by your self.

```
# Somewhere in your template filters and tags

@register.filter
def InList(value, list_):
  return value in list_.split(',)
```

and in your template:

```
{% load inlist %}

{% if not '1'|InList:'5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13' %}
<div>1 is not inside</div>
{% endif %}

{% if '5'|InList:'5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13' %}
<div>5 is inside</div>
{% endif %}
```

I've just tested it. It works.

br